# How does the swtor subscription work in steam?

Tags: steam, star-wars-the-old-republic

I bought a 30 day subscription for star wars the old republic via Steam, after which I received an email from them (not steam) telling me that they'd charge me every month to renew.

Is that true? Will I automatically be charged through steam? (BioWare doesn't have my CC info)

I thought it was a one-time 30 day buy (since you can even buy more time in one chunk)

For the record I plan on keep subscribing for a while longer but I'm unsure if I should manually buy more time, wait to be charged automatically, or what

Comment: Were you forced to buy through credit card? Or are there also other payment options available that would make it otherwise impossible for steam to charge you recurringly?

Comment: I used wallet balance @Mixxiphoid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EA/BioWare's direct subscription options are also for different chunks of time (you save a couple bucks per month, they get you to subscribe for longer).  This is likely exactly the same and they just have Steam charge you.  However, I'm finding some conflicting information about whether Steam's variety is actually non-recurring.

You can always cancel the subscription now, and decide what to do once your current 30 days are up.  If you plan on playing more, you may want to do that and just pick one of the longer plans.

Comment: So, follow up question... how can I unsubscribe then? I can't find the subscription anywhere

Comment: This should help @juan: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8018-TAJK-6238#manage

Comment: Yeah I saw that but I can't find subscriptions anywhere in my account details page... strange

Comment: I searched a little more and I'm finding conflicting information on whether a Steam SWTOR "subscription" is recurring or not.  I'd suggest you send a ticket in to Customer Service in-game @juan to ask about the email you received and whether you will indeed be re-billed automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I can always wait and see what happens too... I asked a follow up question here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374663/what-happens-if-my-swtor-subscription-ends-and-i-immediately-renew-it