# What happens if my swtor subscription ends and I immediately renew it?

Tags: steam, star-wars-the-old-republic

Following up on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374514/how-does-the-swtor-subscription-work-in-steam), I'm not sure if I'll be automatically charged to renew my SWTOR subscription since I bought 30 days using wallet balance via Steam and not credit card.

So the solution will be to wait and see, but I don't want to lose anything in the experiment.

What will happen if my subscription ends and then I buy more time soon after?

Comment: Are you able to buy more days before your current amount expire? Ive never played SWTOR but another game I play that has a subscription model lets you buy as many days as you want, you don't have to wait for your current subscription to end first.

Comment: Yes @KyleRone, I can add time if I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll drop to the Preferred experience in the intervening time, but upon resubscribing everything will be exactly the same as it was.  You won't lose anything.

Comment: I usually immediately cancel after subscribing to most services so they don’t auto-renew and I can confirm for SWTOR that there are no ill effects. Renewing almost instantaneously restores subscription benefits if I recall correctly. There’s also no advantage to waiting until the subscription expires to renew it if you have the money. The days are added to the subscription length.

Comment: That matches my experience also.